# Access dict objects from json dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json that includes a dict and a list. I want to loop only the dict objects and stop the loop.

```
json_res = {
  "abc": "123",
  "Students": [
 { 
  "Sub1": {
  "Name":"Amit Goenka" 
   },
  "Sub2": {
  "Major":"Physics" , 
  "Name2":"Smita Pallod" 
   },
   "Sub3": {
  "Major2":"Chemistry" , 
  "Name3":"Rajeev Sen" , 
  "Major3":"Mathematics" 
   }
},
[
 [
"Name",
0,
"Student",
1
  ]
 ]
]

}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
for data in json_res['Students']:
  val = data.get('Sub3')
```

this results:

```
{
  "Major2":"Chemistry" , 
  "Name3":"Rajeev Sen" , 
  "Major3":"Mathematics" 
   }
```

and fails. I want to consider the loop only from "Sub1" till "Sub3".

Comment: As [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) _Lists are mutable sequences, **typically used to store collections of homogeneous items** (where the precise degree of similarity will vary by application)._ It is strange, so to say, to have a list (the value for key `Students`) that contains both `dict` and `list`. Where do you get this response from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the isinstance to check for dict.

```
for data in json_res['Students']:
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        val = data.get('Sub3')
        print(val)
```